# How to check Kendo Observable has changed

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-observable

Hi I have a form that contains Certain fields and I have made it as Kendo Observable as follows

```
var TITLE = $("#TITLE").val().trim();
var DESC = $("#DESC").val().trim(); 

 Analysis.Kendo_VM = kendo.observable({
     TITLE: TITLE != null ? TITLE : "",
     DESC: DESC != null ? DESC : "",
 });
```

I want to Check if there is any changes made to this Observable.
For that we use hasChanges() or dirty() function But that's not supporting in my case.

```
var isdatasrc_changed = Analysis.Kendo_VM.hasChanges()
```

OR

```
var isdatasrc_changed = Analysis.Kendo_VM.dirty()
```

it should return true if changes has been made to the Observable.But Getting error that hasChanges() and dirty() is Undefined.

Answer (score 4):

[`dirty`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#fields-dirty) is a **field** of the Kendo UI Model object, while [`hasChanges`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-hasChanges) is a **method** of the Kendo UI DataSource object. Neither of these are available for the Kendo UI ObservableObject.

You can use the [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject#events-change) **event** to track changes in observable objects.